# Is this group representation faithful? Von Dyck group (2,3,8).

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-presentation

Let, $G=\left\langle a,b\ |\ a^2,b^3,(ab)^{8}\right\rangle$.

Is the following a faithful representation?

$a\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}-1+\sqrt{2} & -1 & -2 \\-1 & -3+\sqrt{2} & -2+2\sqrt{2}\\-\sqrt{2} & 2-\sqrt{2} & 2-2\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}$

$b\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1+\sqrt{2} & -2 \\1-\sqrt{2} & -1+ 2 \sqrt{2} & -2+2\sqrt{2}\\\sqrt{2} & 2-\sqrt{2} & 2-2\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}$

The matrices do satisfy the above relations. And many other products I've tried don't equal the identity. I suspect this is faithful, but I don't know how to approach a proof.

I should add how I found this representation, as it looks like magic. I was thinking about how you can place $3$ triangles around a vertex to get a regular tetrahedron, $4$ for an octohedron, $5$ for icosahedron. And these live nicely in Euclidean space. With $8$ triangles around each vertex you get a tiling of a hyperbolic surface which doesn't live nicely in Euclidean space.

So let's put it there anyway.

At each vertex, instead of wrapping 8 triangles once around a vertex, if you wrapped them twice around each vertex, you would cover an octohedron. If instead you wrap them $3$ times around each vertex, you can still put the whole tiling in Euclidean $3$ space, but maybe without any triangles coinciding. It intersects itself all over the place, and is infinite, so a picture doesn't help. But, you can find matrices which represent rotation around a specific edge ($a$) or triangle ($b$).

To make things easier I required $ab$ to correspond to a rotation of $3/8$ of a turn around the z axis. Then I cleaned up the representation a bit.

Thoughts?

Comment: The connection between von Dyck groups and tilings is well-known, and it implies that all of the hyperbolic von Dyck groups have faithful representations into $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$, the isometry group of the hyperbolic plane, which itself has a faithful $3$-dimensional representation into $SO(2, 1)$ coming from the hyperboloid model of the hyperbolic plane. So that produces some faithful $3$-dimensional representation, which may be equivalent to this one.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks. I will investigate along that direction.

Comment: The group does not preserve a form of type (2,1) but does preseve a positive definite form with diagonal entries $(1,1,1/\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: There is a standard representation of a triangle group in $SU_2$ and then this gives a represention into $SO_3$ (via quaternions). I think your representation is conjugate to that one.